# Eloquent select records form last 30 days

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I having a list of records that have a date (like `11/5/2013`, that's a MDY formt), but the dates are `VARCHAR` fields.

I want to select all the records that are in the last 30 days, but don't know how to cast them to date format, as I get NULL in dates field.

I'm using Laravel and Eloquent ORM, how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need an accessor in your model.

Assume your have a `dates` field in your table.

```
public function getDatesAttribute($value)
   {
     $this->attributes['dates'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $value);
   }
```

The above function will convert the date from string to Carbon object. By default Laravel support Carbon.

**Now from you controller:**

```
$test = Test::where('dates', '>=', Carbon::now()->subMonth())->get();
```

I haven't tested the code but should work. :)